# Заполнить массив элементами из Enum

Tags: c#

Подскажите, нужно заполнить массив, не где не могу найти как работать толково с типом enum.

```
Card[] deckCards = new Card[52];


CreateDeckCards()
        {
            for (int i = (int)Lear.Clubs; i < (int)Lear.Spades; ++i)
            {
                for (int j = (int)Rank.Ace; j < (int)Rank.Two; ++j)
                {
                    deckCards[i] = new Card(Lear[i], Rank[j], true); //Что не так делаю? 
                }
            }
        }
```

Вот на всякий случай конструктор класса Card

```
public Card(Rank rank, Lear lear, bool isFaceUp)
        {
            //TODO: Тут должна быть проверка

            c_Rank = rank;
            c_Lear = lear;
            this.isFaceUp = isFaceUp;
        }
```

Comment: cannot implicitly convert type

Comment: Это случайно не из книжки Джона Шарпа пример?

Comment: В строчке `deckCards[i] = new Card(Lear[i], Rank[j], true);` поменяйте местами Lear[i] и Rank[j] при вызове метода

Comment: не, даже не слышал про Джона Шарпа, хорошая книга?